# Dynamic help missing in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I am following a Lynda tutorial on basic Java programming and it's a few years old and they are using Java 6.

During the tutorials he often selects a section of code, such as 'Date' then selects the Dynamic Help which brings up a Javadoc all about that command.

When I try this I get the following error in a popup window:

> Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.

How can I get the dynamic help to work? Does it work differently in Java 8? I am using Eclipse Juno on Win7.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a JRE (Java Runtime Environment) instead of a JDK (Java Development Kit) configured in your Eclipse. To fix this, go to `Window -> Preferences`, select `Java -> Installed JREs` and use the `Add` button to select the path to a JDK. Check the checkbox in front of the new entry to make it the default. The JavaDoc should now be available from the dynamic help.